How do you sign and verify a .deb file using debsigs and debsig-verify?
I found it extremely difficult to set up deb file signing and signature verification using debsigs and debsig-verify. There is an old HOWTO out there that is much-referenced, but does not work at least for contemporary versions of these tools.
I did ultimately get it to work, so I'm posting this question with my answer in case it helps others. Every individual challenge I ran into has solution out there somewhere after enough digging, but I couldn't find anything that ties it all together into a process that works.
This is based on debsigs 0.1.26 and debsig-verify 1.20.9.

Background
After installing debsigs, you can find detailed info under /usr/share/doc/debsig-verify/, in:

policy-syntax.txt
examples/

Notes

debsig-verify works with packages signed by debsigs, not dpkg-sig
The relevant directory names and command options imply that you use keyring files

I couldn't get that to work. One post I found said "they are keys, not keyrings." That worked.


XML namespace & dir structure in .pol file must match output of debsig-verify --version

(be careful about http vs https)


A gpg "key id" is the last 16 hextets of the key's fingerprint

This is the "short id," and is indicated as insecure in some references
I did not see any way to get debsigs to use long key ids (last 32 hextets)
I couldn't find a way to get gpg to give me a key id, and I found counting 16 chars to copy/past error-prone, so I used cut in my solution.



HOWTO
# create key
    gpg --full-generate-key
    # follow prompts; for testing it's easier to use no passphrase

# add key for debsigs in KEY_ID dir
    KEY_ID=`echo -n <key fingerprint> | cut -c25-`
    echo -n $KEY_ID | wc -c # must be 16 chars
    KEY_DIR=/usr/share/debsig/keyrings/$KEY_ID
    mkdir $KEY_DIR
    gpg --export $KEY_ID > $KEY_DIR/debsig.gpg # not ascii & not a keyring

# create XML policy
    POL_DIR=/etc/debsig/policies/$KEY_ID
    mkdir $POL_DIR
    vi $POL_DIR/my-app.pol
    # copy/paste example from /usr/share/doc/debsig-verify/examples/
    replace example id= value w/ $KEY_ID
    replace File= value with debsig.gpg

# sign package
    debsigs --sign=origin --default-key=$KEY_ID my-app-2.1.0.deb
    # You should be prompted for key's passphrase - if not, sort that out directly w/ gpg first
    # if there is a KDE desktop running, the prompt may pop-up in the GUI in a dialog box

# verify package
    debsig-verify --debug --verbose my-app-2.1.0.deb

# utility commands
    # show signature in .deb
    debsigs --list my-app-2.1.0.deb 
    # note: some debsigs versions (0.01.19) crash when signature starts with comment
    #       upgrade to newer version (0.1.26)
    # show gpg packets from signature file
    ar x my-app-2.1.0.deb _gpgorigin # extract the signature 
    gpg --list-packets _gpgorigin

